Is there a finite upper bound for the minimal number of generators of a Boolean clone?
A Boolean clone is a clone (in the sense of universal algebra) on the set $\{0,1\}$. Post proved that every Boolean clone is finitely generated. I want to know if a stronger version of Post's theorem holds. What I want to know is if there is a natural number $n$ such that every Boolean clone has a generating set with at cardinality at most $n$. I suspect that this stronger version is false, but I don't know a proof either way.

What I want to know is if there is a natural number  such that every Boolean clone has a generating set with at cardinality at most . I suspect that this stronger version is false, but I don't know a proof either way.
Let $\kappa$ denote the least cardinal number such that every Boolean clone has a generating set of size at most $\kappa$. I claim that $\kappa=3$.
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be Post's lattice.
If $G=\{f_1,\ldots,f_m\}$ is a least-size generating set for a Boolean clone $C\in\mathcal{P}$, then for each $i=1,\ldots,m$ there will be a lower cover $M_i\prec C$ containing $G-\{f_i\}$. These lower covers must be distinct, so we may conclude that the number of lower covers of $C$ in $\mathcal{P}$ is an upper bound on the size of a least-size generating set for $C$. If you examine the picture of $\mathcal{P}$ below, you will see that every $C\in \mathcal{P}$ has at most $4$ lower covers. This is enough to show that every $C\in\mathcal{P}$ can be generated by at most $4$ elements, hence $\kappa\leq 4$.
To prove that $\kappa=3$, it suffices to (i) examine all $C\in \mathcal{P}$ that have exactly $4$ lower covers and prove that those clones can be generated by $\leq 3$ elements, and (ii) exhibit some Boolean clone that requires $3$ generators.
To do (i), there are only $6$ clones $C\in\mathcal{P}$ that have $4$ lower covers. It is not too much work to show that each one can be generated by $\leq 3$ elements. (For example, the top clone has $4$ lower covers, but it can be generated by a single element - NAND.) To do (ii), argue that the clone generated by $\{0, 1, \wedge\}$ cannot be generated by $<3$ elements.

